# Minimum post title workaround on initial post, but not on edits

Tags: bug, title

I posted a question a few minutes ago with the title `One more thing...` which comes to 14 characters and 3 dots. It was posted as `One more thing` since I assume SO automatically strips `...`, which I can agree with. I went back to edit it, and the title wouldn't accept since it was fewer than 15 characters. I modified the title to "One more thing..." again, and it would not accept that time. I ended up changing the title to `Just one more thing...` and it was posted as `Just one more thing`.

I couldn't find this already asked, so I'm trying to reproduce the issue with this post. Hold tight, please don't close this question just yet. If I can't reproduce it, I'll delete this question myself.

**edit**

- "13 char title..." was successfully posted as "13 char title".
- Editing as "13 char title..." is not accepted.
- Editing as "18 character title..." posted as "18 character title"